# SystemError exception on deployment

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Now the following lines of code works fine on local server, but on deployment, it raises `SystemError exception`. I have been trying to figure out where the exception is coming from but everything looks fine or perhaps there is something am not doing right. Would be so glad if someone could give a hand.

Here is my code

```
def watermark(img, mark, position=(0, 0), opacity=1, scale=1.0, tile=False, greyscale=False, rotation=0, return_name=False, **kwargs):
    """
    Adds a watermark to an image.
    """
    if opacity < 1:
        mark = reduce_opacity(mark, opacity)

    if type(scale) != tuple:
        scale = determine_scale(scale, img, mark)

    mark = mark.resize(scale, Image.ANTIALIAS)

    if greyscale and mark.mode != 'LA':
        mark = mark.convert('LA')

    rotation = determine_rotation(rotation, mark)
    if rotation != 0:
        # give some leeway for rotation overlapping
        new_w = mark.size[0] * 1.5
        new_h = mark.size[1] * 1.5

        new_mark = Image.new('RGBA', (new_w, new_h), (0,0,0,0))

        # center the watermark in the newly resized image
        new_l = (new_w - mark.size[0]) / 2
        new_t = (new_h - mark.size[1]) / 2
        new_mark.paste(mark, (new_l, new_t))

        mark = new_mark.rotate(rotation)

    position = determine_position(position, img, mark)
    print position

    if img.mode != 'RGBA':
        img = img.convert('RGBA')

    # make sure we have a tuple for a position now
    assert isinstance(position, tuple), 'Invalid position "%s"!' % position

    # create a transparent layer the size of the image and draw the
    # watermark in that layer.
    layer = Image.new('RGBA', img.size, (0,0,0,0))
    if tile:
        first_y = position[1] % mark.size[1] - mark.size[1]
        first_x = position[0] % mark.size[0] - mark.size[0]

        for y in range(first_y, img.size[1], mark.size[1]):
            for x in range(first_x, img.size[0], mark.size[0]):
                layer.paste(mark, (x, y))
    else:
        layer.paste(mark, (0, 0))# Traceback points this line, but it doesn't look wrong to me

    # composite the watermark with the layer
    return Image.composite(layer, img, layer)
```

stack trace

```
 SystemError at /

 new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple

 Request Method:    POST Request URL:   example.com/ Django Version:
    1.7.1 Exception Type:   SystemError Exception Value:    

 new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple

 Exception Location:

    /path/to/app/lib/python2.7/PIL/Image.py in paste, line 1334 

 Python Executable:     /usr/bin/python Python Version:     2.7.5

    /path/to/app/folder/watermark.py in watermark

 214.    layer.paste(mark, (0, 0))

 /path/to/app/lib/python2.7/PIL/Image.py in paste

 1334.    self.im.paste(im, box)
```

Comment: Maybe you have Pillow installed in development, but not in production?

Comment: It might be caused by `mark` and `new_mark` having different modes. You could try to make sure both are RGBA before pasting. The exception message is really unhelpful, so I'm guessing here.

Comment: thanks, I tried that but the error still persists

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by using different versions of PIL or Pillow in development and deployment. I recommend using Pillow, since it's better supported.

The mode "LA" is only [partially supported](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes). So that might be the reason why this operation is raising an exception.

> PIL also provides limited support for a few special modes, including LA (L with alpha)

I think the code should work if you use RGBA instead of LA. PIL might not recognize the LA format as an image, and try to interpret it as a colour tuple.

[Image.paste()](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html?highlight=paste#PIL.Image.Image.paste)

> Instead of an image, the source can be a integer or tuple containing
>   pixel values. The method then fills the region with the given color.
>   When creating RGB images, you can also use color strings as supported
>   by the ImageColor module.

Comment: None of the above seem to be the problem as I have tried them and the error still persists